# Replacing files using copy/Xcopy in command prompt

Tags: batch-file, command-line, scripting, batch-processing

Hi Everyone,
            I am looking to execute a command as a part of by code (only in cmd batch script)
where i can update a (copy) list of files from server 1 to server 2.  The catch is that

1. \\server_1\Folder might contain much more files than \\server_2\folder. So i want to only copy the files that are present in server 2 from server 1.
2. \\server_1\Folder\ file lists and \\server_2\Folder\ file lists are dynamic

doing this in python scripting seems pretty simple. But i have to complete these copy operations only in Windows command mode, is there a way to automate it? Help please

Comment: xcopy /u will only copy files that exist in destination.

Comment: Use [`robocopy`](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)